# Add people who have used contribution page to a group (or tag them)

Tags: contribution-page

I want to add everyone who made a contribution from a particular contribution page to a group.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: having just provided an answer, i guess i am now not clear if you mean you want this to by dynamic, or you want to find people who did this in the past and add them to a group, or both. For people who did it in the past you should be able to search for Contributions (in Advanced Search) and filter by the 'contribution page'

Comment: Thanks Ramesh and Petednz,
Using advanced search and selecting the contribution page was what I needed.
Also thx for tip to amend the profile to add people who fill it to a group.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge - If you have set up an unique financial type for the contribution page it would be easy or if you have an unqiue label in the contribution source that might help too

Select all the contact using advance search - filter all the contact based on financial type id or using contribution source or date based on the contribution - in the contribution section

once you got the list - add to a specific group manually - done

But you need to do this each time manually - may be wait for someone to give you more precise answer

thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two options.

If you use a unique civicrm Profile on that Contribution Page then you can set that Profile to add people who fill it in to a Group.

Second option is that I believe CiviRules extension can provide this sort of action based on a Trigger of Contribution Created together with the Condition of the source (not totally certain on that latter though)